# How to remove duplicates from an unordered Immutable.List()?

Tags: immutable.js

How would one remove duplicates from an unordered Immutable.List()? 
(without using toJS() or toArray())

e.g.

```
Immutable.List.of("green", "blue","green","black", "blue")
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can convert it to a Set. A Set is a List with unique values.

```
Immutable.List.of("green", "blue","green","black", "blue").toSet()
```

If you need it as list again just convert it back then:

```
Immutable.List.of("green", "blue","green","black", "blue").toSet().toList()
```

**Update:**

It exists a shorter possibility to get unique values:

```
Immutable.List.of("green", "blue","green","black", "blue").distinct
```

Comment: Using Immutable 3.7.3 the `.distinct` solution does not seem to work (it's undefined). `.toSet().toList()` does the job!

Comment: for Immutable 3.8.2 as well - ```.distinct``` returns ```undefined```

Comment: immutable@4.0.0-rc.12 `.distinct` returns `undefined`

Comment: Is there a way to use `Seq.Set` to lazily remove duplicates?

Comment: Note that `toOrderedSet().toList()` is likely what one wants (so the orderer in the list is preserved but repeating entries are removed).

Answer (score 30):

If you have a more complex type you can also use groupBy to provide your own selector to compare on. The following will remove duplicates on the property `.name`:

```
var distinctColors = duplicateColors.groupBy(x => x.name).map(x => x.first()).toList();
```